# Were the arches on medieval bridges large enough to permit river traffic?

Tags: middle-ages, bridge

I’ve been looking through the Civitates Orbis Terrarum to get a sense of the way Medieval cities and their surroundings were organized, but there are some questions I haven’t been able to answer about the logistics of river trade.

Were the arches on any bridges large enough to permit river traffic to pass under them? If not, would a river boat simply ferry up- and downriver between bridges? (i.e., would goods commonly have to be loaded and unloaded multiple times along the same river?)

Is this bridge, for example, large enough to accommodate a barge? ([Lincoln High Bridge, built 1160 CE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High_Bridge,_Lincoln)) Where I’m from, they need to raise the bridges to let barges pass.

(Edited to narrow scope)

EDIT 2: Thanks to everyone who’s responded so far. I know there were some bridges clearly able to accommodate river traffic, but a river is only as navigable as the smallest bridge along its course. If there is any single bridge your boat can’t fit under, it’s an impassible barricade, no matter how many other bridges will let you pass. If they ran into a bridge like that, did they haul the barge over land? Or, per my original question, did a barge only travel as far as bridges would allow it, requiring goods to be transferred between multiple boats over the course of their transport?

Comment: This is too broad. Too many questions covering too large an area.

Comment: The overwhelming majority of river traffic is, and always has been, on barges - which easily fit under arched river bridges.

Comment: Special adaptations were made in some cases to allow the river boats to lower their mast when reaching bridges, see [Thames Sailing Barge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thames_sailing_barge): *The masts are mounted in tabernacles so they can be lowered to pass under bridges*

Comment: @kenkujukebox - depends entirely on the size of the barge. Modern barges have a much larger profile than historical ones

Comment: If you were at all sensible, you would build your barges or boats so they fit through the arches of existing bridges.  And if you were building a new bridge on a river that already had traffic, you'd size the arches to accomodate the traffic.  You might look at the narrowboats that carried cargo (and still carry tourists &c) on the British canal system: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Narrowboat

Comment: Old London Bridge permitted river traffic, didnt it ?

Comment: I guess the barges in the _Civitates Orbis Terrarum_ are not to scale. [This one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Georg_Braun#/media/File:Braun&Hogenberg_Trier_1572.jpg), on Wikipedia, clearly shows arches.

Comment: Certainly in any big town, you only have to stand on the bridge for a while to see boats go under the arches. Obviously if you want to use a boat in a certain river or canal you build one which will fit under the bridges, even if the boatman has to duck.

Comment: @jamesqf You'll see plenty of bridges and tunnels _just barely_ big enough for a narrowboat to pass under in CountryHouseGent"s  _[Travels by Narrowboat](https://www.youtube.com/user/CountryHouseGent)_  YouTube channel, which for some reason I find mesmerizing.

Comment: @Spencer: That might be a chicken or egg thing, the narrowboats having been built as wide as they could be and still fit through the bridges & tunnels.

Comment: @jamesqf Yes, they probably evolved together. And of course the [egg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Egg) is far more ancient than the chicken ;).

Comment: @jamesqf the critical design feature for the UK narrow canal system was the locks, not the bridges and tunnels. Bridges also had to be tall enough for a horse to walk under the bridge along the towpath, pulling the barge, Locks need to be as small as possible to use the minimum amount of water, and also to be easily hand-operated. Having chosen the maximum barge size of 7 x 70 ft (giving a cargo capacity of about 40 tons for two barges towed by one horse), the locks prevented bigger boats using system. The clearance around a barge in a lock is literally inches at the sides, and fore and aft.

Answer (score 26):

*Why would you think that medieval people would build such impractical bridges?*

After all, there are surviving medieval bridges, which are perfectly capable to allow river traffic.

[image: Stone Bridge]
[Stone Bridge in Regensburg, Germany from the 12th century](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone_Bridge_(Regensburg))

---

**Edit**: the OP is interested in non-navigable bridges.
There is consensus in the comments, that in terms of economy a ferry offers the benefit of not hindering river traffic while allowing for road traffic across the river. A non-navigable bridge would only allow road traffic across the river, while all goods transported on the river would need to be loaded between barges up- and down-river.
As river traffic was more economical in the past, a ferry would be the preferred solution.

*So, what about non-navigable brides?*

Wikipedia offers several examples of bridges, which are quite narrow (in terms of span-width).

[image: The Anping bridge]
[The Anping bridge in China from the mid 12th century](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anping_Bridge)

[image: The Arkadiko Bridge]
[The Arkadiko bridge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arkadiko_Bridge), although I am not sure whether it spans a navigable water way.

An example of a non-navigable bridge
[image: The Tarr Steps]
[The Tarr Steps](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarr_Steps) from somewhere between the Bronze Age and 1400 AD, yet I am not sure whether it spans a navigable water way.

---

Yet another topic addressing the question: *un-loading and re-loading the cargo*.

In medieval law there was a thing named [Staple right](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Staple_right), which forced a merchant to offer his goods in a place (city) that had the Staple right.
So a trader would have to unload the cargo, and offer it on the local market for a prescribed period. Afterwards the cargo can be loaded again on a river barge.
In such a scenario, there would be an actual incentive to build a bridge with a quite narror span, as it would prevent anybody from simply passing the city.

Comment: Worth noting that the bridge in this picture is built such that arches rest on wide platforms which extend both along and against the water flow - one of those platforms purpose is to prevent ships from crashing into arches.

Comment: I guess that another "feature" of the those prismatic platforms is to serve as ice-breaker (also referred to as [Starling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Starling_(structure))), at least on the upstream side.

Comment: @DohnJoe: I expect that they also have the effect - on both upstream and downstream side - of reducing eddies in the current - again aiding barge traffic by making steering easier.

Comment: Your rhetorical question has an easy answer:  Because — maybe — they weren't capable of creating higher and wider arches but still in need for a sturdy bridge to allow land travel.  After all this is reason sometimes pontoon-bridges are installed.

Comment: @Alfe Water transportation (where it is possible) has traditionally been less costly than land transportation, especially for freight. So I find your argument unconvincing.

Comment: @Spencer In general: sure.  At some specific spots, e. g. within a larger settlement: not necessarily.  And if they — maybe — lacked the capability to build higher, wider bridges, then they still could at some spot build at least a bridge to allow crossing the water without allowing water traffic anymore.  In fact, had the question been "ten thousand years ago" instead of "medieval", the answer might have been exactly this.

Comment: @Alfe No, this economy holds true up to the spread of railroads in the 19th Century. If someone lacked the capability to build a higher bridge over a navigable waterway, they would made do with a ferry, or have found some other way (such as a lift bridge) to accommodate water traffic.

Comment: As your photo shows, the Arkadiko Bridge runs over a narrow culvert that seems to be completely dry most of the time. There's no way that creek was ever navigable even before the bridge was built, except by foot. (I even [checked Google Maps](https://goo.gl/maps/wuB4DUgNHswx4daJ7) to make sure there wasn't more to the bridge than shown in the photo. There isn't.)

Comment: As for the Tarr Steps, [another photo from Wikipedia](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Tarr_Steps_01.jpg) shows that the water isn't more than knee-deep at most. Apparently it's even possible to drive a car across the river just upstream of the Steps, and [a Google Street View driver apparently did just that.](https://goo.gl/maps/xmcDoXcZWyvowk9u5) Google also finds several pictures of [people wading in the river](https://goo.gl/maps/1duBMgaEXfwyHpEQA) as well as [taken by them](https://goo.gl/maps/qYyDdqxpHUmoniRh6).

Comment: @Spencer In your reply you say more or less, if they lack the ability to build a better bridge, they'd build a better bridge in a different way.  That's a bit besides the point.  The proposition of the argument was that they _cannot_ build a better bridge.  Based on this proposition the argument holds.  Ferries are always there before the bridges, but at some point a society might feel that it is a good decision to replace the ferry by a bridge, even if it means to block the river traffic.  As I said, I guess you'd have to look back way further than just medieval to find such times.

Answer (score 2):

The old [London Bridge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/London_Bridge#%22Old%22_London_Bridge_(1209%E2%80%931831)) (1209-1831) not only had arches wide enough for river traffic, it had a lifting drawbridge in the middle to allow tall ships to pass through it. It’s true, however, that the current through the arches was very rapid because of the obstruction to the river from the bridge’s structure.